# mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property with abstraction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, h2

I have the following classes and I'm trying to store all the derived classes in one table (aircraft).
But I get the above error, of course, I was searching for a solution for a while, and tried to play with the mappedBy name value as well...

What am I missing?

```
@Entity // for hibernate
@Table // for database
public class Airline {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "airline_sequence",
            sequenceName = "airline_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "airline_sequence"
    )
    private long airline_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "airport_id")
    private Airport homeAirport;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "aircraft", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Aircraft> airplaneList;
```

```
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn
@Entity
public abstract class Aircraft implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "aircraft_sequence",
            sequenceName = "aircraft_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "aircraft_sequence"
    )

    // Data members
    private long aircraft_id

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "airline_id")
    private Airline airline;

    @Version
    private Long version;
```

```
@Entity // for hibernate
@Table // for database
@DiscriminatorValue("Airplane")
public class Airplane extends Aircraft {

    //Constructors here
```

Comment: do you have a stacktrace of the exception associated to the provided mapping?

Comment: will it change anything if you remove @DiscriminatorColumn from Aircraft and @ Table from Airplane?

Comment: @tremendous7 No.

Comment: @tremendous7 Cant add stack trace, "too much code error"
[Stack trace](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VPGqrg0qkXHXDAOm5wqby9eppNZD5xz-7JXxOXCMPYY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: do you need both mapping Aircraft.airline and Airline.airplaneList?

Comment: @tremendous7 What do you mean by saying both mapping?

Comment: should this `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "aircraft", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` be `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "airline", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` instead?

Comment: @tremendous7 You solved that! Thanks a lot